Transportation problem with transit limitations
I need to find the solution to transportation problem with transit limitations and below there is the code which works correctly.
However I don't know how to input these limitations in the code.
Lower bound:












1
2
1
2
1


2
1
1
1
3


0
1
2
1
1


2
1
3
1
2



Upper bound:












9
8
6
10
5


7
15
4
6
9


5
6
6
5
10


8
5
7
4
8



All your ideas will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

import pandas as pd
import pulp

truck_capacity = 6
suppliers = pd.RangeIndex(name='supplier', stop=4)
consumers = pd.RangeIndex(name='consumer', stop=5)

supply = pd.Series(
    name='supply', 
    index=suppliers, 
    data=(17, 8, 10, 9),
)
demand = pd.Series(
    name='demand', 
    index=consumers, 
    data=(6, 15, 7, 8, 8),
)
price_per_tonne = pd.DataFrame(
    index=suppliers, columns=consumers,
    data=(
        (10,  8,  5,  9, 16),
        ( 4,  3,  4, 11, 12),
        ( 5, 10, 29,  7,  6),
        ( 9,  2,  4,  1,  3),
    ),
).stack()
price_per_tonne.name = 'price'

flow = pd.DataFrame(
    index=suppliers, columns=consumers,
    data=pulp.LpVariable.matrix(
        name='flow_s%d_c%d', cat=pulp.LpContinuous, lowBound=0,
        indices=(suppliers, consumers),
    ),
).stack()
flow.name = 'flow'

trucks = pd.DataFrame(
    index=suppliers, columns=consumers,
    data=pulp.LpVariable.matrix(
        name='trucks_s%d_c%d', cat=pulp.LpInteger, lowBound=0,
        indices=(suppliers, consumers),
    )
).stack()
trucks.name = 'trucks'

price = truck_capacity * pulp.lpDot(price_per_tonne, trucks)
prob = pulp.LpProblem(name='transportation', sense=pulp.LpMinimize)
prob.setObjective(price)

# The flow must not exceed the supply
for supplier, group in flow.groupby('supplier'):
    prob.addConstraint(
        name=f'flow_supply_s{supplier}',
        constraint=pulp.lpSum(group) <= supply[supplier],
    )

# The flow must exactly meet the demand
for consumer, group in flow.groupby('consumer'):
    prob.addConstraint(
        name=f'flow_demand_c{consumer}',
        constraint=pulp.lpSum(group) == demand[consumer],
    )

# The capacity must be able to carry the flow
for (supplier, consumer), truck_flow in flow.items():
    prob.addConstraint(
        name=f'capacity_s{supplier}_c{consumer}',
        constraint=truck_flow <= trucks[(supplier, consumer)] * truck_capacity
    )


 

print(prob)
prob.solve()
assert prob.status == pulp.LpStatusOptimal

print(f'Total price: ${price.value():.2f}')
print()

print('Flow:')
flow = flow.apply(pulp.value).unstack(level='consumer')
print(flow)
print()

print('Trucks:')
trucks = trucks.apply(pulp.value).unstack(level='consumer')
print(trucks)
print()

print('Prices:')
print(trucks * truck_capacity * price_per_tonne.unstack(level='consumer'))



Does this mean, for example, that supply point 1 (the first supply point) has a supply of 17, of which between 1 and 9 units must go to demand point 1 (the first demand point), between 2 and 8 units must go. to demand point 2, and so on? If so you can simplify the problem by reducing 17 to 17 - (1 + 2 + 1 + 2 + 1) = 10 and changing the upper bounds for supply point 1 from [9, 8, 6, 10, 5] to [9-1, 8-2 ,6-1 ,10-2 ,5-1] #=> [8, 6, 5, 8, 4] and do the same for each of the other supply points...

...That will convert all the minimum shipments from each supply point to each demand point to zero. The upper bound still complicate the transportation problem, however.

@CarySwoveland As I understand your idea, you're right. We cannot transport less than 1 and more than 9 units from supply point 1 to demand point 1. The same story is about supply point 1 and demand point 2: only between 2 and 8 units are able to be delivered and so on.

Transportation problems are linear programming (LP) problems that have two important properties: 1) every transportation problem has an optimal solution whose variables are integer-valued; and 2) they can be solved using specialized algorithms (versus, in particular, the Simplex method.) Even if you perform the simplification I outlined, you are still left with a generic linear programming problem that cannot be solved using by transportation problem algorithms and whose optimal solution is not guaranteed to have (and generally would not have) integer-valued variables.

Call bounds once for every lower/upper flow bound:
import pandas as pd
import pulp

truck_capacity = 6
suppliers = pd.RangeIndex(name='supplier', stop=4)
consumers = pd.RangeIndex(name='consumer', stop=5)

supply = pd.Series(
    name='supply',
    index=suppliers,
    data=(17, 8, 10, 9),
)
demand = pd.Series(
    name='demand',
    index=consumers,
    data=(6, 15, 7, 8, 8),
)
price_per_tonne = pd.DataFrame(
    index=suppliers, columns=consumers,
    data=(
        (10,  8,  5,  9, 16),
        ( 4,  3,  4, 11, 12),
        ( 5, 10, 29,  7,  6),
        ( 9,  2,  4,  1,  3),
    ),
).stack()
price_per_tonne.name = 'price'

flow = pd.DataFrame(
    index=suppliers, columns=consumers,
    data=pulp.LpVariable.matrix(
        name='flow_s%d_c%d', cat=pulp.LpContinuous,
        indices=(suppliers, consumers),
    ),
).stack()
flow.name = 'flow'

flow_lower = pd.DataFrame(
    index=suppliers, columns=consumers,
    data=(
        (1, 2, 1, 2, 1),
        (2, 1, 1, 1, 3),
        (0, 1, 2, 1, 1),
        (2, 1, 3, 1, 2),
    ),
)
flow_upper = pd.DataFrame(
    index=suppliers, columns=consumers,
    data=(
        (9,  8,  6, 10,  5),
        (7, 15,  4,  6,  9),
        (5,  6,  6,  5, 10),
        (8,  5,  7,  4,  8),
    ),
)
for (supplier, consumer), flow_value in flow.items():
    flow_value.bounds(
        low=flow_lower.loc[supplier, consumer],
        up=flow_upper.loc[supplier, consumer],
    )

trucks = pd.DataFrame(
    index=suppliers, columns=consumers,
    data=pulp.LpVariable.matrix(
        name='trucks_s%d_c%d', cat=pulp.LpInteger, lowBound=0,
        indices=(suppliers, consumers),
    )
).stack()
trucks.name = 'trucks'

price = truck_capacity * pulp.lpDot(price_per_tonne, trucks)
prob = pulp.LpProblem(name='transportation', sense=pulp.LpMinimize)
prob.setObjective(price)

# The flow must not exceed the supply
for supplier, group in flow.groupby('supplier'):
    prob.addConstraint(
        name=f'flow_supply_s{supplier}',
        constraint=pulp.lpSum(group) <= supply[supplier],
    )

# The flow must exactly meet the demand
for consumer, group in flow.groupby('consumer'):
    prob.addConstraint(
        name=f'flow_demand_c{consumer}',
        constraint=pulp.lpSum(group) == demand[consumer],
    )

# The capacity must be able to carry the flow
for (supplier, consumer), truck_flow in flow.items():
    prob.addConstraint(
        name=f'capacity_s{supplier}_c{consumer}',
        constraint=truck_flow <= trucks[(supplier, consumer)] * truck_capacity
    )

print(prob)
prob.solve()
assert prob.status == pulp.LpStatusOptimal

print(f'Total price: ${price.value():.2f}')
print()

print('Flow:')
flow = flow.apply(pulp.value).unstack(level='consumer')
print(flow)
print()

print('Trucks:')
trucks = trucks.apply(pulp.value).unstack(level='consumer')
print(trucks)
print()

print('Prices:')
print(trucks * truck_capacity * price_per_tonne.unstack(level='consumer'))

Result - Optimal solution found

Objective value:                966.00000000
Enumerated nodes:               0
Total iterations:               0
Time (CPU seconds):             0.00
Time (Wallclock seconds):       0.00

Option for printingOptions changed from normal to all
Total time (CPU seconds):       0.00   (Wallclock seconds):       0.00

Total price: $966.00

Flow:
consumer    0    1    2    3    4
supplier                         
0         2.0  8.0  1.0  5.0  1.0
1         2.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  3.0
2         0.0  5.0  2.0  1.0  2.0
3         2.0  1.0  3.0  1.0  2.0

Trucks:
consumer    0    1    2    3    4
supplier                         
0         1.0  2.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
1         1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
2         0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
3         1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0

Prices:
consumer     0     1      2     3     4
supplier                               
0         60.0  96.0   30.0  54.0  96.0
1         24.0  18.0   24.0  66.0  72.0
2          0.0  60.0  174.0  42.0  36.0
3         54.0  12.0   24.0   6.0  18.0


Thanks. I did it only for upper bound and in a different way, but it works
`constraint_matrix = [
[9,  8,  6, 10,  5],
[7, 15,  4,  6,  9],
[5,  6,  6,  5, 10],
[8,  5,  7,  4,  8]
]
Add constraints for each element in the matrix
for i, row in enumerate(constraint_matrix):
for j, value in enumerate(row):
prob.addConstraint(
name=f'constraint_{i}_{j}',
constraint=flow[(i, j)] <= value,
)
`

Solution only for upper bound, but it works
import pandas as pd
import pulp

truck_capacity = 6

suppliers = pd.RangeIndex(name='supplier', stop=4)
consumers = pd.RangeIndex(name='consumer', stop=5)

supply = pd.Series(
    name='supply', 
    index=suppliers, 
    data=(17, 8, 10, 9),
)
demand = pd.Series(
    name='demand', 
    index=consumers, 
    data=(6, 15, 7, 8, 8),
)
price_per_tonne = pd.DataFrame(
    index=suppliers, columns=consumers,
    data=(
        (10,  8,  5,  9, 16),
        ( 4,  3,  4, 11, 12),
        ( 5, 10, 29,  7,  6),
        ( 9,  2,  4,  1,  3),
    ),
).stack()
price_per_tonne.name = 'price'

flow = pd.DataFrame(
    index=suppliers, columns=consumers,
    data=pulp.LpVariable.matrix(
        name='flow_s%d_c%d', cat=pulp.LpContinuous, lowBound=0,
        indices=(suppliers, consumers),
    ),
).stack()
flow.name = 'flow'

trucks = pd.DataFrame(
    index=suppliers, columns=consumers,
    data=pulp.LpVariable.matrix(
        name='trucks_s%d_c%d', cat=pulp.LpInteger, lowBound=0,
        indices=(suppliers, consumers),
    )
).stack()
trucks.name = 'trucks'

price = truck_capacity * pulp.lpDot(price_per_tonne, trucks)
prob = pulp.LpProblem(name='transportation', sense=pulp.LpMinimize)
prob.setObjective(price)

# The flow must not exceed the supply
for supplier, group in flow.groupby('supplier'):
    prob.addConstraint(
        name=f'flow_supply_s{supplier}',
        constraint=pulp.lpSum(group) <= supply[supplier],
    )

# The flow must exactly meet the demand
for consumer, group in flow.groupby('consumer'):
    prob.addConstraint(
        name=f'flow_demand_c{consumer}',
        constraint=pulp.lpSum(group) == demand[consumer],
    )

# The capacity must be able to carry the flow
for (supplier, consumer), truck_flow in flow.items():
    prob.addConstraint(
        name=f'capacity_s{supplier}_c{consumer}',
        constraint=truck_flow <= trucks[(supplier, consumer)] * truck_capacity
    )


constraint_matrix = [
    [9,  8,  6, 10,  5],
    [7, 15,  4,  6,  9],
    [5,  6,  6,  5, 10],
    [8,  5,  7,  4,  8]
]

# Add constraints for each element in the matrix
for i, row in enumerate(constraint_matrix):
    for j, value in enumerate(row):
        prob.addConstraint(
            name=f'constraint_{i}_{j}',
            constraint=flow[(i, j)] <= value,
        )
print(prob)
prob.solve()
assert prob.status == pulp.LpStatusOptimal

print(f'Total price: ${price.value():.2f}')
print()

print('Flow:')
flow = flow.apply(pulp.value).unstack(level='consumer')
print(flow)
print()

print('Trucks:')
trucks = trucks.apply(pulp.value).unstack(level='consumer')
print(trucks)
print()

print('Prices:')
print(trucks * truck_capacity * price_per_tonne.unstack(level='consumer'))



Don't use a constraint when a bound is enough. This may imply performance differences in some solvers.

@Reinderien Thanks. I'd like to ask you one more question: I'm trying to find out how iterations are counted. I'm looking for some info and cannot find something on it. Depending on data it can be several dozens, but sometimes the number of iterations is more than 1000. Thanks in advance!

LP performance is non-trivial to analyse. I wouldn't worry about it unless it becomes a problem.

@Reinderien I need to provide this info, that's why I'm interested in number of iterations.
